# With Sheets("").Range("B:B"); Variable range when searching

Tags: vba, variables, excel, find

Here´s the thing, I have a code that uses a fixed range in a fixed sheet to search for a value. I need now to make the sheet variable. I´ve tried couple of things with no luck so far.
The name of the sheet where I need to search is determined by a cell in another sheet. Replacing the 3rd line with something like: "With Sheets("Sheets("asd").range("A1")").Range("B:B") does not work.

My code:

```
    FindString = W
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(**"CARS"**).Range("B:B")
                   Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

Let me know if more info is required.
Thanks!

Comment: Try omitting some of the doublequotes: `With Sheets(Sheets("asd").range("A1")).Range("B:B")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "With Sheets("Sheets("asd").range("A1")").Range("B:B")

by:

```
dim VAR_Sheet as string
Var_Sheet=Sheets("asd").range("A1").value
With Sheets(Var_Sheet).Range("B:B")
   ...code...
end with
```

works also like this (same result):

```
With Sheets(Sheets("asd").range("A1").value).Range("B:B")   'removed quotes that made error
```

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting some of the doublequotes: With Sheets(Sheets("asd").range("A1")).Range("B:B")

**Explanation**

When you do this, you'll get a *compile error: Expected list separator or )*:

```
With Sheets("Sheets("asd").range("A1")").Range("B:B")
```

This is because the double-quotes encapsulate a string literal, so in this case the string literal is `"Sheets("`, which raises an error at `asd` (and subsequent errors, too).

The solution is to simply refer to the `Sheets("asd")` object, there is no need to qualify that object within quotes :)

**NOTE** Brad identifies another potential error in your code, see his answer below.

Comment: aye, very true. :) nice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, while you types `With` you are actually not using it.

```
With Sheets("CARS").Range("B:B")
           Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=FindString, _  <~~ Cells references the active sheet
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
```

You need to start the statement with a dot to signify you are continuing the reference established int eh `With`

```
With Sheets("CARS").Range("B:B")
           Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _  <~~ .Cells
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
```

I assume the double `*` was for emphasis (`Sheets(**"CARS"**)` --> `Sheets("CARS")`)

Comment: I want to +1 this because it is a good catch, but it doesn't answer the OP's actual question...

Comment: @DavidZemens Doesn't it? OP thinks they are searching a range but they are not actually because their range reference is not established correctly?

Comment: Re-read the question: **I need now to make the sheet variable(** and further **The name of the sheet where I need to search is determined by a cell in another sheet. Replacing the 3rd line with something like: "With Sheets("Sheets("asd").range("A1")").Range("B:B") does not work.**  While your answer identifies another potential problem in OP's code, that is not the question being asked :)